# Cannot refer to a non-final variable str inside an inner class defined in a different method - How to fix this?

Tags: java, android, sockets

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
String str;
while ((str = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView newMsg = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            newMsg.setText(str);

            newMsg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (
                                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                        m_receivedMessagesLayout.addView(newMsg);
            }
    });
}
```

Here is the code. If I try to bring the loop into the UI thread, then it won't work because Android doesn't allow sockets on the main thread. I need the `str` as I need it to be a variable so can't make it final. What's a clean solution to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Declare another `final` variable within the `while` loop that gets assigned the value of `str` on each run.

Comment: @Sotirios - if you write that as an answer, then I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply declare another variable inside your `while` loop which is `final` and gets assigned the value of `str`. This variable is local to the `while` loop and will get recreated on each iteration. You can then use that variable in your `Runnable`'s `run()` method.

```
while ((str = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    final String value = str;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView newMsg = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            newMsg.setText(value);

            newMsg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (
                                                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                                        m_receivedMessagesLayout.addView(newMsg);
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not allowed to create socket in activity you Should use

AsyncTask<..,..,..>

to implement your code

Comment: I intend to listen for incoming messages on a socket that's already running. I want this to be running indefinitely. According to the docs though, it's only supposed to be used for limited time. Is there something else that can be done?